# Consuming a Soap Client in Xamarin Visual Studio 2017 - Dublin Bus Real Time Information

Tags: c#, xamarin, soap, xamarin.android, soap-client

I would appreciate some help, I am fairly new to programming.

I am trying to consume a soap client in Xamarin using Visual Studio 2017. 
The Soap Client is for the real time information for a bus service.

From Researching the topic I understand adding the 'WSDL' as a web reference to VS 2017, I am just wondering the best way to call the information into the Xamarin application.

http://rtpi.dublinbus.ie/DublinBusRTPIService.asmx?WSDL

I have added the Soap Client (WSDL) as a web reference (above)

I have attempted to consume the data using C#

I have created a interface

```
namespace Soap
{
    public interface RealTimeInfo
    {
        bool GetRealTimeStopData(string data);
    }
}
```

I created a get 'RealTimeInfo' class

```
 [assembly:Dependency(typeof(Soap.Droid.GetRealTimeInfo))]

namespace Soap.Droid
{
    public class GetRealTimeInfo : RealTimeInfo
    {
        public bool GetRealTimeStopData(string data)
        {
            var RTPIService = new ie.dublinbus.rtpi.DublinBusRTPIService();
            bool returnoRealTimeStopData = RTPIService.GetAllDestinations(data);
            return returnoRealTimeStopData;
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: have you read the docs?   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/data-cloud/web-services/walkthrough-working-with-wcf

Comment: Thank you for the help!